Getting all <a> Tags even after changes on the page
In the Mailstore Webclient there sadly aren't a lot of features.
All the folders are <a> Tags with the name scheme "archives-tree-view-0-expand-link".
"Mein Archive" = archives-tree-view-0-expand-link
"Exchange kevin.krippner" = archives-tree-view-0-0-expand-link
So what I have been trying is to inject a script that gets all the <a> tags and looks if the id of that tag includes -expand-link.
If that is the case than I do .click() on that ElementByID to open it.
It works for the first instance of "Mein Archiv" but after that I somehow need to get all <a> tags again after "Mein Archive" has opened since they aren't all shown/selectable from the start (subtree is hidden.)
const tags = document.querySelectorAll("a")
    console.log("Current Amount of <a> Tags: " + tags.length)
    var icounter=0
    var opened = new Array;
    while(icounter<document.querySelectorAll("a").length){
         tags.forEach(a=>{console.log("Testrun:");if(a.getAttribute("id").includes("-expand-link")==true){
            if(opened.length==0 || opened.includes('""')||opened.includes(a.getAttribute("id"))== false){
                console.log(a.getAttribute("id")+" has been clicked.");
                document.getElementById(a.getAttribute("id")).click();
                opened.unshift(a.getAttribute("id"));
            }}else{console.log("No <a> Expand Tag clicked")}})
        console.log("New Amount of <a> Tags: " + tags.length)
        icounter++
        console.log("New Amount of <a> Tags:" + (document.querySelectorAll("a")))
        if(tags.length<document.querySelectorAll("a").length){
            console.log("Tags Reset: " + tags)
            tags=document.querySelectorAll("a")
            icounter=0
            lo=0
        }
    }

Simply checking if there is more <a> tags with another querySelectorAll doesn't seem to work.
Structure

Generally, if you really want to learn programming, you should get used to the idea of harsh judgement. Your code as posted is not good; many things about it should be changed. That does not make you a bad person.

@Pointy You got a point. Im aware that my code is not optimal in any form. Im just trying to apply the basics im currently learning in school :) Always happy to know how to do it properly out in the "real" world.

@Yogi Looking at that it makes sense. I assume once i do the .click() it doesnt automatically update. That's why I can't get the correct value I want with another querySelectorAll

You can select all the anchor elements that have their ID end with -expand-link using this selector a[id$="-expand-link"] (eg: document.querySelectorAll('a[id$="-expand-link"]')) and you can monitor for changes to the page to get the newly added such elements using a MutationObserver

You solved this already? @CruyerVS. Using MutationObserver as @Titus says should work fine. If not, please give me the example HTML of the page you would like to querySelectorAll (instead of just an image) so I can show the way to do it.
